# Shortcode Initialization in a Custom Theme

Tags: functions, themes, shortcode

I have a custom theme I'm developing, and when I use the easy digital downloads plugin it seems the shortcodes aren't working.

When you develop a theme, is there any code you need to add to your functions.php file to allow shortcodes to work generally (I'm not referring to setting up specific or individual shortcodes in your functions.php file).

Many thanks

Comment: Nothing should need to be done to enable shortcodes.  This should work by default.  Perhaps there are other install steps for that plugin?

Comment: I've tried it in a downloaded theme and it works straight out of the box.  I'll have see what else could be causing the problem. Thanks.

Comment: I would try an incredibly simple shortcode of your own, deactivating the plugin.  This would tell you if there is a problem with your theme or the plugin.  Although it sounds like you've mostly isolated the theme already.

Comment: @jdm2112 that's not a bad shout.  I've just tried doing a simple shortcode that returns some text and it's not showing up on my page content (I did the same thing in the child theme of a premium theme and it worked).  I wonder why the shortcodes aren't working?

Comment: I solved it !!! I had `the excerpt()` instead of the `the_content()` in my page.php template.  I googled "shortcodes not working" after I found out the above from your suggestion.  Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear you found the problem.

Comment: @TheChewy Please post the solution you found as an answer, then stop by in a few days and click the checkmark to accept it. This makes the solution more visible to future users and will remove the question from the unanswered queue. Thank you!